# How to include a particular directory for checking with mypy

Tags: python, mypy

In the `mypy.ini` file I have:

```
[mypy]
exclude = ['tests', 'build']
```

Which works alright as long as both of these directories exists - if one of them doesn't exist then I get the following error message:

```
There are no .py[i] files in directory '.'
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to exclude these directories without this error - or if not - if there's a way to explicitly tell mypy which directories it should check.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `exclude` expects a *regular expression* in the INI file ([see docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-exclude)). I'm not great with regex, but you can start off with

```ini
[mypy]
exclude = (build|tests)
```

The [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-exclude) on the `--exclude` parameter is also useful (copied relevant parts below.

> A regular expression that matches file names, directory names and paths which mypy should ignore while recursively discovering files to check. Use forward slashes on all platforms.
> For instance, to avoid discovering any files named setup.py you could pass --exclude '/setup.py$'. Similarly, you can ignore discovering directories with a given name by e.g. --exclude /build/ or those matching a subpath with --exclude /project/vendor/. To ignore multiple files / directories / paths, you can provide the –exclude flag more than once, e.g --exclude '/setup.py$' --exclude '/build/'.

Also see https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10310 for relevant discussion.

Comment: I initially tried this using a regex string, but this ended up being what was needed `exclude = (build|tests|setup.py$)` in my case, thanks

Comment: Excellent. What does the `$` do?

Comment: signals that it should be the end (so it'll match setup.py but not setup.pyi for example).